# Elastic search indexing for more then 1000 unique fields

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to understand is there any limitation from ELK side to the numbers of fields that can be indexed? Our schema has a Map fields and it has many unique fields in it, the index size is growing and slowing down ELK. Do you have recommendations around that can be done to optimize it? It has been communicated by our infra team that ELK has a limitation of indexing only 1000 unique fields (is it true?) Also I would like understand what we can do to optimize this, as we don't really have any restriction on the users of what they can put in that Map field. As of now we have around 800 unique fields in the logs. Any recommendations?

Comment: It's hard to answer without more information. What are your data? Can you purge them? The first thing to do is to work on your mappings. If you work with log / temporal documents, you can split them in different index (one by month) and congifure less shards on the old one for example (or delete them). You can in the settting configure more fields, but there is a cost. The true question is do you really need 800+ fields :)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! Yes I need 800+ fields as I am handling data from 20+ products and each product has these fields for experiments and they want to search based on these fields! I am dread to think that I will hit the 1K limit unique field limit soon. So was thinking is there a way by which I can optimize my ELK indexing.

Comment: So index.mapping.total_fields.limit allow you to go more than 1000 fields / index but you need to be really carrefull about it. You cant split your data in several indexs? According to es this isnot a good practice :S